# Sum of array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have a array suppose

```
[#<Data id: 1, date: "2016-01-06", value: "1">,
 #<Data id: 2, date: "2015-12-31", value: "3">,
 #<Data id: 3, date: "2016-01-06", value: "6">...]
```

and so on..

I want to sum the values having same date

i.e here first and third record are of same date so the result array will give

```
 #<Data id: 1, date: "2016-01-06", value: "1">,
 #<Data id: 3, date: "2016-01-06", value: "7">,
```

Comment: Hey try to group it as `arr.group_by{|a| a.date.to_date}`

Comment: Why is this data in an array, these are ActiveRecord objects - can you gather them as an ActiveRecord Collection instead of an array?

Comment: `array.group_by{|aa| aa.date}.map{|k,v| Date.new(1, k, v.inject(0){|s,p| s + p.value})}` do you try this ? in a ruby type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey you can use try this way if you have already fetch an array from database

```
  arr.group_by{|a| a.date.to_date}.map{|k,v| {k => v.map(&:value).sum()}}
```

If you are are not fetch array/active record from database you can directly use database query as
   If your database stores only `date` then you can use

```
Model.group("date").sum(:value)
```

If your database stores `date with time` here i have use `DATE_FORMAT` function for skipping Time part of date

```
  Model.group("DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y%m%d')").sum(:value)
```

Comment: Yes, this one should work -
    
Data.all.group_by{|a| a.date.to_date}.map{|k,v| {k => v.map(&:value).sum()}}

Answer (score 3):

You can use sql groupping on the model:

```
Data.where(date:(42.days.ago..Date.today)).group(:date).sum(:value)
```

This will return a hash of `{date => sum}`

On an array:

```
Hash[your_array.group_by(&:date).map{|k,v| [k, v.sum(&:value)]}]
```

Comment: It gives NoMethodError: undefined method `group' for array

Comment: Not on an array, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

sum = Hash.new(0)

array.each do |data|

```
  <p>sum[data[:date]] += data[:value]</p>
```

end

# => {:id => 1, "Wed, 04 May 2011" => 300, "Tue, 03 May 2011" => 450...}

# =>  If you then want this in the same array format you started with:

new_array = sum.collect{ |key, value| {:date => key, :value => value} }

# => [{:id => 1,:date => "Wed, 04 May 2011", :value => 300}, {....}]